# How do I link a compiled ".so" library with Scons?

Tags: c, build, shared-libraries, scons

I have an existing `.so` library (libgit2), and I would like to use this within a C program (the build system is Scons). I read through the entirety of the [Scons documentation for "Chapter 4. Building and Linking with Libraries"](https://scons.org/doc/4.0.1/HTML/scons-user/ch04.html), but there is no mention of how to use an existing `.so` library. The only mention of `.so` in the entirety of chapter 4 is on the first page, and it is only about Scons using a `.so` file for output. How do I use an existing compiled `.so` library in Scons?

Comment: Was this answered on our discord channel? If so, please post the solution below and mark it an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an sconscript then you should add a `LIBS=` arguments and a `LIBS_PATH=`.

if you want to directly add it to the build line, use `-L` for lib path and `-l` to link a lib.

You can find further information here: https://scons.org/doc/0.97/HTML/scons-user/x628.html

Comment: This is the right concept (it's `LIBPATH` rather than `LIBS_PATH`). Though preferably, use a more current version of the doc (not saying that section has changed, but 0.97 is quite old). https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/ch04s02.html

Comment: I already tried adding `-L` for the lib path and `-l` to link the lib, but it did not work.

Comment: How do I use `LIBS=` and `LIBPATH=` without `Program()`? I am not compiling an exectuable program, I am compiling a C library that uses another library (sorry if "program" was ambiguous).

Answer (score 0):

With help from the SCons Discord server and other places, I've gotten farther than when I first posted this question. I haven't solved my specific problem of using `.so` libraries with GDNative, but I think I've figured out the SCons side.

As of me posting this question, the SConstruct file was able to compile working code if I didn't use libgit2 and instead just printed out the text. With only the header included, my test call to `git_libgit2_version` compiled but didn't run, as Godot said `undefined symbol: git_libgit2_version`.

First of all, you need to add the named parameter for `LIBS` to your `env.SharedLibrary` or `env.Program` line. The `lib` prefix and `.so` suffix seem to be added automatically, I still haven't figured out how to make it point to `libgit2.so.1.0.1` (so for now I have the library copied and named as `libgit2.so`, but I would like to have it point to `libgit2.so.1.0.1` eventually instead). Also, the SCons team suggested adding `LIBPATH`, but this doesn't seem to actually do anything.

```py
library = env.SharedLibrary(target=env["target_path"] + env["target_name"] , source=sources, LIBS=['git2'])
```

Then, the SConstruct file needs to have this magic line:

```py
env['STATIC_AND_SHARED_OBJECTS_ARE_THE_SAME'] = 1
```

With the above code, `ldd` will report `not found`, and Godot will say `Error: libgit2.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` (I have no idea why it's asking for `.so.1.0` instead of the `.so` or `.so.1.0.1` file, and yes I tried copying and naming as `libgit2.so.1.0` and that doesn't change anything either).

I also added this, which was [suggested](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/20765) by another GDNative user.

```py
env.Append(LINKFLAGS=[
    '-Wl,-rpath,addons/git_for_godot/gdnative/linuxbsd'
])
```

With all of the above code, this seems to allow `ldd` and Godot to find the library just fine with a relative path (when running `ldd` you have to be `cd`'d into the project folder). I can run the project fine without any errors, but the project crashes immediately after opening, with no error messages printed. If I comment out the call to `git_libgit2_version` but keep the header included, the file does compile and run. Any time I try to call anything from `libgit2` it causes Godot to crash without printing any errors. At this point I'm stuck and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I did try adding `libgit2` to the Dependencies section of the `.gdnlib` file, but this doesn't seem to affect anything. Another thing I tried which didn't work is this line (+ variants on the extension) which append to the sources list passed as the named `source` parameter. I'll post it here for completeness, but for the moment I have this line commented out because it doesn't work:

```py
sources.append(File("project/addons/git_for_godot/gdnative/linuxbsd/libgit2.so"))
```

Answer (score 0):

for current scons, it's quite buried in the the [documentation](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#app-variables) but if you have an existing environment you can do the following:

```
env.Append(LIBS=File('/tmp/mylib.so'))
```

and it will add the named `.so` to the linker line for you.